# Keeping flow from screen resize for media queries, icon locations and font size

Tags: css, resize, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I've got a couple of problems, Using media queries I change the position and font size for mobile/tablet and desktop, the problem is, if your changing the window size the font size and a couple of social icons are taken out of place.

So mobile 320, tablet 768, desktop 960-1280+ are the sizes I've designed for.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .footer-top ul.links li {
        font-size: 0.60em; 
        }
        ul.home-social {
        width:73%;
        margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    }
    }
```

This is the example of font change and social icon position, but if the window is resized by the user the icons are out of place. Any Idea's ? I just want it to flow well or is there no point?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I just want to say one thing, that the sizes of phones, tablets, etc are all extremely relative. While you may have designed something for 320 and for 768 the varying sizes of all of the different phones and ALL of the different tablets is going to make it impossible to make a pixel-perfect design for each.

As far as the position of the elements and font sizes being affected by the user changing the size of the window and it being incorrect, you'll have to find a way to align them so that they work well within whatever size they are currently being viewed at. Instead of having text next to the icons and messing with trying to get both Alignment and Font-Size to work based on a lot of screen sizes, try breaking them out so that the icons and the text are on two different horizontal lines, possibly?